# How to know the selected cipher suit on openssl

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, handshake

I'm using openssl library and implementing a application with c-language.

The question is: how to get the selected cipher suit on the phase of `psk_server_cb`?

My application should be using selected (negotiated) cipher to make PSK so I have to get the selected cipher before completing session handshake.
I have tested with `SSL_get_current_cipher()` but it was returned with `null` because the session was not established in the `psk_server_cb` phase.

Is there a way to get the selected cipher for the phase of `psk_server_cb` or before?